# Windows Forms: How do I disable `ListView` scroll animation (smooth-scrolling)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, animation

ListView scroll animation makes the whole scrolling slow like hell in my computer.

How do I disable `ListView` scroll animation (smooth-scrolling)?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to remove the scrolling for all the windows.

1. Go to "system properties" in windows. (Control panel->System->Advanced system settings)
2. Click on "Advanced" tab
3. remove the checkbox from "Animate controls and elements inside windows" and "smooth-scroll list boxes".

(Frankly I just use the radio button "adjust for best performance" which removes all the animation and smooth scrolling. I just hate them!)

Comment: Tried it, it does not affecting .NET's `ListView` even in "adjust for best performance" mode. :(

Comment: @DxCK sorry to hear that. I tried the ListView right now and I could not reproduce you problem. Do you have more information about this, like what properties do you have on ListView and so on?

Comment: I activated `ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer` and `ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint`, `VirtualMode`, `SmallImageList`, `View`=`Details`, `FullRowSelect`, `HideSelection`=`false`, `AllowColumnReorder`, `VirtualListSize`=`1000000`

Comment: Check if the callback-function does not take that much time. I tested on my computer with a sleep(20) and the scrolling was very slow.

Comment: Tested with minimal callback-function, still happens. Try scroll with Page-Up & Page-Down buttons.

Comment: Did you succeeded to reproduce the behavior?